# Allow users to multiselect option in BotFramework

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I would like my Bot make surveys. The problem is that in some questions, the user could select more than 1 answer.

How could I implement this scenario? Is there an official sample on how to do it with version 3 of the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that in some questions, the user could select more than 1 answer.

To enable user to select more than 1 answer to question(s), you can use `AdaptiveChoiceSetInput` to achieve the requirement. The following code snippet is for your reference.

```
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = "Q1:xxxxxxxx?",
    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder
});

card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput()
{
    Id = "choiceset1",
    Choices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>()
    {
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer1",
            Value="answer1"
        },
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer2",
            Value="answer2"
        },
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer3",
            Value="answer3"
        }
    },
    Style = AdaptiveChoiceInputStyle.Expanded,
    IsMultiSelect = true
});
```

*Test result:*

[image]

Comment: It's working! But now, how can I retrieve what the user has selected? 

Comment: Hi @SuperJMN! This is an almost entirely different question "How to save and retrieve user responses from FormFlow with adaptive cards". Can you repost it as a separate question (with code snippet, example, what you're attempting, etc) so that the community can better work with you on it?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Done! you can find the new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264144/how-to-save-and-retrieve-user-responses-from-formflow-with-adaptive-cards