# How to save and retrieve user responses from FormFlow with Adaptive Cards?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm using an **Adaptive Card** with a multiselect, in the context of Bot created with [BotBuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) ([Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)):

```
var card = new AdaptiveCard();
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
    Text = "Q1:xxxxxxxx?",
    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default,
    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder
});

card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput()
{
    Id = "choiceset1",
    Choices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>()
    {
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer1",
            Value="answer1"
        },
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer2",
            Value="answer2"
        },
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer3",
            Value="answer3"
        }
    },
    Style = AdaptiveChoiceInputStyle.Expanded,
    IsMultiSelect = true
});

var message = context.MakeMessage();

message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment() { Content = card, ContentType =  "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"});    
await context.PostAsync(message);
```

Now, I would like to know which elements the user has selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know which elements the user has selected.

You can get user's selections from message `Value` property, the following code snippets work for me, please refer to it.

```
if (message.Value != null)
{
    var user_selections = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<userselections>(message.Value.ToString());

    await context.PostAsync($"You selected {user_selections.choiceset1}!");
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

*The definition of `userselections` class:*

```
public class userselections
{
    public string choiceset1 { get; set; }
}
```

*Test result:*

[image]

**Update:** *Code snippet of adding AdaptiveChoiceSetInput and AdaptiveSubmitAction*

```
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput()
{
    Id = "choiceset1",
    Choices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>()
    {
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer1",
            Value="answer1"
        },
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer2",
            Value="answer2"
        },
        new AdaptiveChoice(){
            Title="answer3",
            Value="answer3"
        }
    },
    Style = AdaptiveChoiceInputStyle.Expanded,
    IsMultiSelect = true
});


card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
{
    Title = "submit"
});
```

Comment: Could you please add the full code? I'm not getting the Submit button :( Thanks in advance!