# Chatbot with multiselect option

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

We have a chatbot which interacts with user based on related queries provided as buttons. But the issue here is he can only select one query through button. So I wanted a way through which user can select multiple query from dropdown or checkboxes. Upon searching I cam across this link:

"[Allow users to multiselect option in BotFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255029/allow-users-to-multiselect-option-in-botframework)"

Now this is something which can help me, but I wanted to confirm that the adaptive card c# bot framework in used in the link can is compatible with Azure bot services or not ??  Can I use this Adaptive Card botframework in Azure bot services ?

I am noob in this and just started with chatbots and all so any suggestion will help or if there is any other better way to implement multi-select options then it will do as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? (I know it answers your question because you linked to it already, but I'm still using the auto-generated text so that it's clear I'm marking this as a duplicate. You question seems to imply that you think the other question is about something other than the Azure Bot Service. The other question was already about the Azure Bot Service, so you're just asking the same question again.) [Allow users to multiselect option in BotFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255029/allow-users-to-multiselect-option-in-botframework)

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes your answer helped. You provided a detailed explanation to my doubt. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adaptive Cards have little to do with the Azure Bot Service. When it comes to whether or not Adaptive Cards are supported, that is entirely determined by the front end because that's where an Adaptive Card renderer would be. In the case of chat bots the front end would be a chat platform, which the Bot Framework calls a bot "channel." It's important to understand that a lot of bot behavior is channel-specific, and so you need to consider what channel you're using. The two main Bot Framework channels that support Adaptive Cards are Microsoft Teams and Bot Framework Web Chat. You can see an official list of platforms that support Adaptive Cards here: https://learn.microsoft.com/adaptive-cards/resources/partners

If you're using a channel that doesn't support Adaptive Cards, there may be some other channel-specific feature that allows users to select multiple options, such as Slack's [block kit](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#checkboxes). If there isn't, then you may have to design the bot to gather information through a dialog. This could be complicated, but the [FormFlow](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow) library might help. If you build your own dialog then there's no reason it couldn't still use buttons. You could have a submit button that the user clicks after they've clicked the other buttons, though this might require some more advanced bot development skills.

If you'd like to know more about Adaptive Cards, please have a look at my blog post: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/